# Activity Bugando + erro de Memoria

Tags: android, android-fragment, objetos

Boa tarde programadores,
estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação e em certa parte dela eu populo textviews com alguns dados provenientes de um webservice. Ao requisitar dados do webservice em uma classe especifica da tudo certo o objeto vem completo, porém ao retornar este objeto a classe do fragmento que devo popular o objeto vem incompleto dando alguns nulls nos textviews, as vezes em todos... E então se eu rotaciono a tela .O console me retorna um erro e da um crash na applicação.

seguem os erros do console:

```
    05-23 11:21:01.256 13392-13392/com.example.pizzamania.maniadepizza E/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = null
05-23 11:21:01.256 13392-13392/com.example.pizzamania.maniadepizza E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@38db738a
05-23 11:21:01.266 13392-13894/com.example.pizzamania.maniadepizza I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-23 11:21:01.281 13392-13392/com.example.pizzamania.maniadepizza I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 16.790ms for cause Alloc
05-23 11:21:01.286 13392-13894/com.example.pizzamania.maniadepizza I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-23 11:21:01.286 13392-13894/com.example.pizzamania.maniadepizza I/System.out: KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
05-23 11:21:01.286 13392-13894/com.example.pizzamania.maniadepizza I/System.out: KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
05-23 11:21:01.311 13392-13392/com.example.pizzamania.maniadepizza I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2174(212KB) AllocSpace objects, 6(912KB) LOS objects, 20% free, 30MB/38MB, paused 953us total 29.953ms
05-23 11:21:01.321 13392-13392/com.example.pizzamania.maniadepizza I/art: Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 20% free, 30MB/38MB, paused 954us total 5.065ms
05-23 11:21:01.356 13392-13392/com.example.pizzamania.maniadepizza I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2538(222KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 20% free, 30MB/38MB, paused 909us total 35.674ms
05-23 11:21:01.361 13392-13392/com.example.pizzamania.maniadepizza I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 2GB allocation
05-23 11:21:01.401 13392-13392/com.example.pizzamania.maniadepizza I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 11(344B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 20% free, 30MB/38MB, paused 883us total 40.670ms
05-23 11:21:01.401 13392-13392/com.example.pizzamania.maniadepizza E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 2284037732 byte allocation with 8388512 free bytes and 225MB until OOM"
05-23 11:21:01.426 13392-13399/com.example.pizzamania.maniadepizza W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.736ms
05-23 11:21:01.431 13392-13392/com.example.pizzamania.maniadepizza I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 6(192B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 20% free, 30MB/38MB, paused 1.796ms total 22.305ms
05-23 11:21:01.466 13392-13392/com.example.pizzamania.maniadepizza I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 7(224B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 20% free, 30MB/38MB, paused 804us total 34.129ms
05-23 11:21:01.471 13392-13392/com.example.pizzamania.maniadepizza I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 2GB allocation
05-23 11:21:01.501 13392-13392/com.example.pizzamania.maniadepizza I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 20% free, 30MB/38MB, paused 774us total 33.736ms
05-23 11:21:01.551 13392-13392/com.example.pizzamania.maniadepizza E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 2284037732 byte allocation with 8388608 free bytes and 225MB until OOM"
05-23 11:21:01.551 13392-13392/com.example.pizzamania.maniadepizza D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
05-23 11:21:01.551 13392-13392/com.example.pizzamania.maniadepizza E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                     Process: com.example.pizzamania.maniadepizza, PID: 13392
                                                                                     java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 2284037732 byte allocation with 8388608 free bytes and 225MB until OOM
                                                                                         at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.<init>(AbstractStringBuilder.java:83)
                                                                                         at java.lang.StringBuilder.<init>(StringBuilder.java:67)
                                                                                         at com.example.pizzamania.maniadepizza.CodMapaPizzarias.carregaSobre(CodMapaPizzarias.java:115)
                                                                                         at com.example.pizzamania.maniadepizza.CodMapaPizzarias.onCreateView(CodMapaPizzarias.java:88)
                                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192)
                                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
                                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
                                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
                                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2900)
                                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
                                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:603)
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
                                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1264)
                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6613)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3153)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3300)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5206)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:211)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1711)
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946)
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Segue também minha classe que busca o objeto no webserver:

```
public class AsyncWebServer {

private static String SOAP_ACTION_INFO = "tempuri.org/MOBILEretornaPizzariasINFO";
private static String NAMESPACE = "tempuri.org/";
private static String METHOD_NAME_INFO = "MOBILEretornaPizzariasINFO";
private static String URL = "http://192.168.0.23/WebService.asmx?wsdl";

private static Context mCont;
static ObjPizzaria obj = new ObjPizzaria();
static ArrayList<ObjAvaliacoes> arrayobj;

public AsyncWebServer(Context m){
    this.mCont = m;
}

public static ObjPizzaria retornaINFO(int id){

    asyncINFO async = new asyncINFO();
    async.execute(id);
    return obj;
}
private static class asyncINFO extends AsyncTask<Integer,ObjPizzaria, ObjPizzaria>{
    @Override
    protected ObjPizzaria doInBackground(Integer... id) {
        ObjPizzaria pizzariaInfo = new ObjPizzaria();

        SoapObject resposta = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME_INFO);
        resposta.addProperty("id", id[0]);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(resposta);

        HttpTransportSE transportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL, 9000);
        String resultado = null;
        JSONArray json = null;
        Base64toBMP imagem = new Base64toBMP();
        try {
            transportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION_INFO, envelope);
            resultado = envelope.getResponse().toString();
            json = new JSONArray(resultado);
            JSONObject jsonObj = json.getJSONObject(0);

            pizzariaInfo.setCep(jsonObj.getInt("CEP"));
            pizzariaInfo.setAval(Float.parseFloat(jsonObj.getString("NOTA")));
            pizzariaInfo.setBairro(jsonObj.getString("BAIRRO"));
            pizzariaInfo.setCidade(jsonObj.getString("CIDADE"));
            pizzariaInfo.setNome(jsonObj.getString("NOME"));
            pizzariaInfo.setCompl(jsonObj.getString("COMPLEMENTO"));
            LatLng ll = new LatLng(jsonObj.getDouble("LAT"), jsonObj.getDouble("LNG"));
            pizzariaInfo.setCoord(ll);
            pizzariaInfo.setEmail(jsonObj.getString("EMAIL"));
            pizzariaInfo.setId(id[0]);
            pizzariaInfo.setLogo(imagem.retornaIMG(jsonObj.getInt("ID_IMG")));
            pizzariaInfo.setLogr(jsonObj.getString("LOGRADOURO"));
            pizzariaInfo.setNumero(jsonObj.getInt("NUMERO"));
            pizzariaInfo.setRefe(jsonObj.getString("REFERENCIA"));
            pizzariaInfo.setSobre(jsonObj.getString("SOBRE"));
            pizzariaInfo.setTelefone(jsonObj.getInt("TELEFONE"));
            pizzariaInfo.setTelefone2(jsonObj.getInt("TELEFONE_2"));
            pizzariaInfo.setUf(jsonObj.getString("UF"));
            obj = new ObjPizzaria();
            obj = pizzariaInfo;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Erro1", e.toString());
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            Log.e("Erro1", e.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Erro1", e.toString());
        }

        return obj;
    }

}
}
```

E a classe do fragmento que recebe o objeto:

```
public class CodMapaPizzarias extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

int id;
ImageView imgLogo;
TextView txtNome;
RatingBar notaMedia;
Button cardapio;
TextView sobre;
TextView rua;
TextView refe;
TextView cidadeUF;
TextView tel1;
TextView tel2;
RatingBar minhaaval;
FloatingActionButton btnLigar;
ToggleButton fav;
ListView listaAval;
Context cont = Contexto.context;


private ObjPizzaria obj;
private ArrayList<ObjAvaliacoes> avaliacoes;

public CodMapaPizzarias() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_tela_mapa_pizzarias, container, false);

    imgLogo = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.sobre_imgLogo);
    txtNome = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.sobre_txtNome);
    notaMedia = (RatingBar) v.findViewById(R.id.sobre_Notapizzaria);
    cardapio = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.sobre_btnCardapio);
    cardapio.setOnClickListener(this);
    sobre = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.sobre_txtVsobre);
    rua = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Sobre_txtvrua);
    refe = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.sobre_txtvRefe);
    cidadeUF = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.sobre_txtvCidadeUf);
    tel1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtv_SobreTel1);
    tel2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtv_SobreTel2);
    minhaaval = (RatingBar) v.findViewById(R.id.sobre_avaliar);
    minhaaval.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnLigar = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.flLigar);
    btnLigar.setOnClickListener(this);
    fav = (ToggleButton) v.findViewById(R.id.tbtnFav);
    fav.setOnClickListener(this);
    listaAval = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.sobre_lstAval);


    if (bundle != null)
    {
        id = bundle.getInt("id");
        carregaSobre(id);
    }
    return v;
}

private void carregaSobre(int id_load) {
    AsyncWebServer asyncWebServer = new AsyncWebServer(cont);
    obj = new ObjPizzaria();
    try {
        obj = asyncWebServer.retornaINFO(id_load);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("Erro1", e.toString());
    }
  //  avaliacoes = asyncWebServer.retornaPizzariaAVAL(id_load);

    imgLogo.setImageBitmap(obj.getLogo());
    txtNome.setText(obj.getNome());
    notaMedia.setRating(obj.getAval());
    sobre.setText(obj.getSobre());
    rua.setText(obj.getLogr()+ ", " + obj.getNumero() + " " + obj.getCompl() + " " + obj.getBairro());
    StringBuilder cep = new StringBuilder(obj.getCep());
    if(cep.length() == 8) {
        cep.insert(5, "-");
    }
    refe.setText(obj.getRefe() + "\n" + cep);
    cidadeUF.setText(obj.getCidade() + "-" + obj.getUf());
    StringBuilder tele1 = new StringBuilder(obj.getTelefone());
    if (tele1.length() == 11) {
        tele1.insert(0, "(");
        tele1.insert(3, ") ");
        tele1.insert(10, "-");
    }
    else if (tele1.length() == 10){
        tele1.insert(0, "(");
        tele1.insert(3, ") ");
        tele1.insert(9, "-");
    }
    tel1.setText(tele1);
    StringBuilder tele2 = new StringBuilder(obj.getTelefone2());
    if (tele2.length() == 11) {
        tele2.insert(0, "(");
        tele2.insert(3, ") ");
        tele2.insert(10, "-");
    }
    else if (tele2.length() == 10){
        tele2.insert(0, "(");
        tele2.insert(3, ") ");
        tele2.insert(9, "-");
    }
    tel2.setText(tele1);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}
}
```

Estou rodando tudo em um galaxy J2 (não sei se isso influencia estes erros).
Me desculpem se for algo obvio, pois sou leigo ainda no assunto...

Answer (score 0):

O erro é simples, exatamente o que está escrito `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 2284037732 byte` 
Erro comum para iniciantes, você esta consumindo muito mais memoria do que o telefone suporta, você esta carregando muitos dados de uma úncia vez pelo seu web-service.

> 2284037732 byte é muita coisa para um app

vi que você esta carregando uma imagem, o erro mais comum é colocarem imagens muitos grandes e não otimizadas para telefones.

1. Não carregue todos os dados do seu banco em uma unica chamada no webservice, se for muitos dados divida em outros endpoints ou carregue dados ao poucos "ex, se for uma lista em vez de carregar todos os itens da lista carregue de 100 em 100"
2. Não envia as imagens pelo webservice, envie apenas o caminho absoluto da URL e use bibliotecas como [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) para exibir as imagens
3. Otimize as imagens ao máximo para ficarem com o menor tamanho possível.

Comment: eu até achei estranho esse tamanho todo ... mas tem uma linha com no máximo 300 caracteres em json e uma imagem de 1mb na outra chamada, não sei pq ta dando td isso ...